# howto upload a file via a single html form to more than just a single server

Tags: javascript, html, forms, amazon-s3

Sending a file/key to Amazon S3 via a html form and HTTP Post is quite easy and working.

But I want to send a file to several S3-compatible sites via HTTP POST and a single html form.

How can I do this?

As far as I know, HTTP POST can only be directed at a single target location.

I want the file to be sent to the first S3-compatible site (server) and then to the second one and than to the third one and so on without any need for the user to interact.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flash to do that for you (a lot easier).

Or I think you can use invisible frames and javascript. Target the upload on the hidden frames and change the action. The example below will upload the same file one server after the other.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){

            $('#frame1').load(function(){
               $('#form1')
                 .attr('action', 'http://server2/')
                 .attr('target', 'frame2')
                 .submit();
            });

            $('#form1')
               .attr('action', 'http://server1/')
               .attr('target', 'frame1')
               .submit();

            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.cgi"> 
      File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile" /><br> 
      Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note" /><br>
    </form>

    <button id="button1">Multiple upload</button>
    <br />

    <iframe id="frame1" name="frame1"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame2" name="frame2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uploading in parallel would be perfect!

Comment: let me know if this is what you want. Remember that u can change the 'action' also to upload to different servers. This example uploads 2 times (one after the other) on the same server.

Comment: This code is very helpful for me. But I don't know how to include more than one server in the action field. Do you have an example with different servers?

Comment: You change it dynamically the same way I change the target. I'll modify my answer to include the change of action.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a last question. For each different server destination I need different hidden fields. How can I give form1 these different hidden files?

Comment: All you have to do is add them dynamically 

$('#form1')
  .append('<input type="hidden" name="hello" value="world" />')
  .attr('action', 'server1')
  .attr('target', 'frame1')
  .submit();

Comment: Puh. I implemented it this way and now there is one problem. When I add hidden fields dynamically via .prepend (append is not working), the fist upload works. But the second one is not working. I think the problem is, that hidden fiels that are prepended, remain in the second upload.

Comment: you have to modify the code accordingly to prepend the fields you need for the first one, remove them for the second one etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain HTML and a browser.

Comment: I'm not sure. It is possible to define a redirect value inside the html form. Maybe I could jump from one form to the next one. Is it possible to add a parameter that submits a html form automatically? I need solution that works on client (browser) side.

Comment: with a redirect, you will lose the file upload.

Comment: But the redirect starts just after the upload was successful.

Comment: a redirect (i.e. "<meta refresh>") will clear the form, "Location:" header also. And it is not possible to re-fill the form file upload automatically.

Comment: no, because when you are done sending the form to the first server, the result page is loaded and you have lost the form and its data. You might want to try this: http://www.captain.at/ajax-file-upload.php